# How to fix "not a functional interface" problem in my code

Tags: java, predicate, functional-interface

I am learning Java predicates and struck here on basic code. Below is my code.

```
package TestLambda;

public class Animal {
    private String species;
    private boolean canHop;
    private boolean canSwim;

    public Animal(String species,boolean canHop,boolean canSwim){
        this.species = species;
        this.canHop = canHop;
        this.canSwim = canSwim;
    }

    public boolean canHop(){return canHop;}
    public boolean canSwim(){return canSwim;}
    public String toString(){return species;}
```

Below is my interface.

```
package TestLambda;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface CheckTrait {
    boolean Test(Animal a);
}
```

Implementing the interface.

```
package TestLambda;

public class CheckIfHopper implements CheckTrait {
    public boolean Test(Animal a){
        return a.canHop();
    }
}
```

Now i am testing a simple Lambda.

```
package TestLambda;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class LambdaSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
        animals.add(new Animal("fish",false,true));
        animals.add(new Animal("dog",true,true));
        animals.add(new Animal("rabbit",true,false));
        animals.add(new Animal("horse",true,false));

        print(animals, a -> a.canHop());
    }

    public static void print(List<Animal> animals,CheckIfHopper checkIfHopper){
        for(Animal animal :animals){
            if(checkIfHopper.Test(animal)){
                System.out.println(animal + " ");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Mycode is throwing error:- TestLambda.CheckIfHopper is not a functional interface

What i am doing wrong please?

Comment: Please do follow the naming conventions. Method names should always start with lowercase letters.

Answer (score 2):

If your purpose is to test lambda expressions, then `CheckIfHopper` is redundant here.

Your `print` method would take a `CheckTrait` parameter:

```
public static void print(List<Animal> animals, CheckTrait checkIfHopper){
    for(Animal animal :animals){
        if(checkIfHopper.Test(animal)){
            System.out.println(animal + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

And the call would be:

```
print(animals, a -> a.canHop());
```

Or the following for brevity:

```
print(animals, Animal::canHop);
```

You can't make a lambda expression to provide an instance of a class, its target type must be a functional interface (this is essentially what the error message is saying)

You don't need the `CheckIfHopper` class, because `a -> a.canHop()` or `Animal::canHop` provide an implementation of `CheckTrait` without a class declaration (that's the point of lambda expressions, isn't it...)

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void print(List<Animal> animals, CheckIfHopper checkIfHopper);
```

CheckIfHopper is a class not a functional interface, you should use CheckTrait instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are exploring lambda with predicates, study filter in streams api.
For example instead of writing the print function above, you can write the code like the one below.

```
animals.stream()
       .filter(Animal::canHop)
       .foreach(System.out::println);
```

Also you can check this link: https://www.journaldev.com/17072/java-predicate